# An insect is moving on a table. How can we express that you put a cup in such a way that it contains the insect inside?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

An insect is moving on a table.

Now you want to capture the insect by putting a cup in such a way that it contains the insect inside.

**How can we express that?**

Can we say "**to lock the insect with a cup**"?

Comment: You have **trapped** the insect by **inverting** a cup over it.

Comment: Put a cup over an insect.

Comment: My girlfriend works in a hospital pharmacy. They had a cockroach infestation in the air ducts. She described what they did while waiting for "Pest Control" to deal with the problem, like this: "We trap them by putting a plastic cup over them, sliding a piece of card underneath and carrying the whole thing outside the clean area, where we insert a piece of cotton wool soaked in chloroform to kill it, then bag it all up and put it in a 'contaminated waste' bin". You don't just squash them because that spreads fragments of dirty insect, and, in the case of females, eggs (which would hatch).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Your comment should be an answer. No, it should be the only answer.

Comment: While the current answer is good, it is far from the only way of describing what's happening. Several other words that could be used in a description include **contain** [used in the question itself], **cover**, **enclose**, **turn**, **rotate**, **upside down**, **display**, **protect**, and **isolate**. The question is simply too open to interpretation to have any single answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My girlfriend works in a hospital pharmacy. They had a cockroach infestation in the air ducts. She described what they did while waiting for the "Pest Control" team to deal with the problem, like this:

> We trap cockroaches by putting a vending machine plastic cup over them, and sliding a piece of card underneath. Then we carry the whole thing outside the clean area,
>   where we insert a piece of cotton wool soaked in chloroform to kill
>   it, then we bag it all up and put it in a 'contaminated waste' bin.

You don't just squash them because that spreads fragments of dirty insect, and, in the case of females, eggs (which would hatch)